# I accidentally installed phased update for gjs. How to revert?

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade

```
~ ❯ apt-cache policy gjs                                                      
gjs:
  Installed: 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500 (phased 0%)
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.72.0-1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

When i try to install the 1.72.0-1 version it wants this which doesn't sound good:

```
~ ❯ sudo apt install libgjs0g=1.72.0-1                                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libgjs0g
```

I know i am stupid for not reading good enough before force upgrading a package, but i hope someone can still help me resolve this issue.

EDIT:

```
~ ❯ sudo apt remove gjs && sudo apt install gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1.487 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 596932 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.481.1) ...
Removing ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481.1) ...
Removing gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng (43-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-characters (41.0-4) ...
Removing gjs (1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.2) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gjs : Depends: libgjs0g (= 1.72.2-0ubuntu2) but 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

~ ❯ apt-cache policy libgjs0g                                          17s
libgjs0g:
  Installed: 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Candidate: 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.72.2-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.72.0-1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

Also i don't have ubuntu-desktop anymore, but everything works still?

```
~ ❯ apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.481.1
  Version table:
     1.481.1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.481 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

I think i need to do this?

```
~ ❯ apt install --simulate libgjs0g=1.72.2-0ubuntu2 gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libgjs0g
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
Inst libgjs0g [1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1] (1.72.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Inst gjs (1.72.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Inst gnome-characters (41.0-4 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Inst gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng (43-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [all])
Inst ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Inst ubuntu-desktop (1.481.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Conf libgjs0g (1.72.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Conf gjs (1.72.2-0ubuntu2 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Conf gnome-characters (41.0-4 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy [amd64])
Conf gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng (43-2ubuntu1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [all])
Conf ubuntu-desktop-minimal (1.481.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
Conf ubuntu-desktop (1.481.1 Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gjs package has been removed from my list of packages that were kept back by phased updates. It was updated as a result of running `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and the following message that packages have been kept back also appeared in the terminal.

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
  language-pack-gnome-en-base libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa-dev libgbm1 
  libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libxatracker2  
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers python-apt-common   
  python3-apt python3-distupgrade qemu-block-extra qemu-system-common   
  qemu-system-data qemu-system-gui qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils  
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unzip
```

These are the results of `apt-cache policy gjs` :

```
gjs:
  Installed: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.72.2-0ubuntu2 500
```

As you can see my gjs version is older than yours, and I also have a long list of packages that have been kept back by phased updates. These kept back packages include essential packages that could cause damage to your system if they were updated incorrectly!

How to resolve this issue without causing damage to your system? Try simulating  uninstalling and reinstalling gjs without making any changes to your system. Run the following command without being root or using sudo.

```
apt remove --simulate gjs && apt install --simulate gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

The results of the simulation command show that my original packages are all still safely installed, gjs is already the newest version (1.72.2-0ubuntu2), and I also got a repeat of the message in my first code block of terminal output that I still have the same not upgraded packages as before that were kept back by phased updates.

Because your version of gjs has a higher number than mine, you should read the results of your simulation command carefully to ensure that downgrading your version of gjs from 1.72.4 to 1.72.2 would not break anything. It's likely that your kept back packages will be different from mine.

The results of simulating `apt remove --simulate gjs && apt install --simulate gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal` on your system show that `ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.481.1)`. It is safe to run this command and restore your package management back to normal.

Then run `sudo apt install libgjs0g=1.72.2-0ubuntu2 gjs gnome-characters gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal` to reinstall the ubuntu-desktop package.

The lesson to take away from this experience is to let apt decide when to upgrade a package that is kept back by phased upgrades. Otherwise manually upgrading a package that is kept back by phased updates could cause damage to your system.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151516/discussion-on-answer-by-karel-i-accidentally-installed-phased-update-for-gjs-ho); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.